# Ошибка TokenMismatchException при попытке получить ответ от Liqpay

Tags: laravel, исключения

После оплаты Liqpay присылает ответ с информацией о транзакции на server_url
Если закоментировать в Kernel.php \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, то ответ от Liqpay приходит. Но это не совсем правильное решение.
Правильнее прописать в классе VerifyCsrfToken что-то вроде этого:
protected $except = [
        'liqpay',
    ];

Но вопрос что прописать? Если писать роут к server_url, то не работает.

Подскажите, как это решить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В `$except` нужно указывать не названия роутов, а урлы. Если вам запрос приходит на урл `https://my_domain/server_url` то нужно указать так:

```
$except = ['server_url'];
```